# Convert youtube url to iframe and remove any surrounding html

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to use the code below to convert a youtube URL to the embedded iframe code. The below is working fine, but the wysiwyg editor often adds `<p>` around plain text so a url such as

```
<p>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJzHXFsU8UQ</p>
```

will output as

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mJzHXFsU9XX&lt</p>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>`

How can I change the below so that it removes the `</p>` from the src?

```
$('body').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/(?:https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making your regex:

`/<p>(?:https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)<\/p>/g`

Debug console test:

`var v="<p>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJzHXFsU8UQ</p>";
 var a = v.replace(
/<p>(?:https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)<\/p>/g,
 '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'
 );
 console.log(a);`

Gives: `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mJzHXFsU8UQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that but for some reason it crashes my web page, and I can't see an error in the console.

Comment: Hrmm... works fine in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/367o4khm/ ... is there more code that might be the issue?  Maybe you can disable things one by one and figure out where the issue is?

Comment: FWIW, I did just notice the "&lt" in your example output above -- that's a less-than symbol, and I'm not sure where it's coming from.  Might be related to your issue, but it looks like your example output isn't from the same input that you posted so it's hard to tell.  What browser are you using?  What WYSIWYG editor were you referring to?